# explode() returns original string

Tags: php, arrays, string, explode

I try to explode a string into an array with:

```
explode('\r\n', $string);
```

I have a form with a text field that is used by the user to enter URLs and the URLs are separated by a new line like so:

```
http://www.example.com/1
http://www.example.com/2
http://www.example.com/3
http://www.example.com/4
```

That should split the string where a new line is found and return an array with all the new strings, but instead `explode()` returns an array with the original string as the frist argument.

```
$string = $_POST['urls'];
$arr = explode('\r\n', string);
```

Expected return:

```
$arr = ['http://www.example.com/1','http://www.example.com/2','http://www.example.com/3','http://www.example.com/4']
```

Actual return:

```
$arr = ['http://www.example.com/1
 http://www.example.com/2
 http://www.example.com/3
 http://www.example.com/4']
```

I know that should work as I have used it before. I must be missing something.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3446216/3933332

Comment: Try using the php constant `PHP_EOL` instead of `'\r\n'`

Comment: Escape sequences aren't processed inside single quotes, only double quotes. Also, be sure that the lines are actually separated by `\r\n`, not just `\n`.